# Difference between CLOCK_REALTIME and CLOCK_MONOTONIC?

Tags: linux, time, clock

Could you explain the difference between `CLOCK_REALTIME` and `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` clocks returned by `clock_gettime()` on Linux?

Which is a better choice if I need to compute elapsed time between timestamps produced by an external source and the current time?

Lastly, if I have an NTP daemon periodically adjusting system time, how do these adjustments interact with each of `CLOCK_REALTIME` and `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`?

Answer (score 333, accepted):

`CLOCK_REALTIME` represents the machine's best-guess as to the current wall-clock, time-of-day time.  As [Ignacio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523442/difference-between-clock-realtime-and-clock-monotonic/3523482#3523482) and [MarkR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523442/difference-between-clock-realtime-and-clock-monotonic/3523857#3523857) say, this means that `CLOCK_REALTIME` can jump forwards and backwards as the system time-of-day clock is changed, including by NTP.

`CLOCK_MONOTONIC` represents the absolute elapsed wall-clock time since some arbitrary, fixed point in the past.  It isn't affected by changes in the system time-of-day clock.

If you want to compute the elapsed time between two events observed on the one machine without an intervening reboot, `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` is the best option.

Note that on Linux, `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` does not measure time spent in suspend, although by the POSIX definition it should.  You can use the Linux-specific `CLOCK_BOOTTIME` for a monotonic clock that keeps running during suspend.

Comment: Note that on newer kernels, CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW is available which is even better (no NTP adjustments).

Comment: @JosephGarvin for some value of "better", perhaps — CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW may run fast or slow of real time by several (or several hundred) parts per million, and its rate might vary due to environmental conditions like temperature or voltage (or steal time on virtual machines). On a properly-working machine, NTP does its best to mitigate all of those factors and so CLOCK_MONOTONIC more closely reflects *true* elapsed time.

Comment: Granted, it might be interesting to have a CLOCK_MONOTONIC_PARBOILED that was affected by NTP's efforts to correct frequency errors, but unaffected by its efforts to correct phase errors, but that's a lot of complexity for a dubious gain :)

Comment: I like the point that @hobbs brings up. What if you're concerned about programs that can be affected by clock drift? Would `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` be the best choice in that scenario? e.g. [Patriot Missile System](http://www.ima.umn.edu/~arnold/disasters/patriot.html)

Comment: I think it's also important to mention that CLOCK_REALTIME is affected by leap seconds. This means that it *will* produce double timestamps every time a leap second is inserted. Last time this happened in June 30, 2012 and quite a lot of software [ran into trouble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second#Examples_of_problems_caused_by_the_leap_second).

Comment: Could you please explain what does the clock could jump forwards and backwards means ? I do not understand that

Comment: @Bionix1441: It means that there can be discontinuities in the time as determined by that clock.  It can repeat previous times that have already happened, or blocks of time can be skipped and never happen.

Comment: @caf This seems to me like a bug in CLOCK_REALTIME. This clock is then definitely unreliable, isnt it ?

Comment: For the record, this last question asked by @Bionix1441 has now been addressed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41894213/what-is-the-use-of-clock-realtime .

Comment: @Bionix1441: No.  `CLOCK_REALTIME` is, as its name suggests, supposed to represent the machine's best idea of the current real, outside world civil time.  It's wristwatch time, and like wristwatch time is subject to correction.

Comment: Can we assume CLOCK_REALTIME is software clock and CLOCK_MONOTONIC is hardware clock?

Comment: @Aadishri: No - in many cases they'll both be derived from the same underlying timebase.  I'm not sure what that assumption would buy you, anyway.

Comment: @caf:  By this assumption, I can rely on one time source untouched by apps like chrony when I say CLOCK_MONOTONIC . This also means I am talking about a HW clock sitting in my board instead of as clock synchronised to external source and not on number of ticks/jiffies

Comment: @Aadishri: The current reading of `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` will not be adjusted by timekeeping applications such as chrony, that's the whole point.  It's *rate* may be disciplined, which is generally what you want.

Answer (score 45):

Robert Love's book **LINUX System Programming 2nd Edition**, specifically addresses your question at the beginning of Chapter 11, pg 363:

> The important aspect of a monotonic time source is NOT the current
>   value, but the guarantee that the time source is strictly linearly
>   increasing, and thus useful for calculating the difference in time
>   between two samplings

That said, I believe he is assuming the processes are running on the same instance of an OS, so you might want to have a periodic calibration running to be able to estimate drift.

Answer (score 34):

`CLOCK_REALTIME` is affected by NTP, and can move forwards and backwards. `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` is not, and advances at one tick per tick.

Comment: CLOCK_MONOTONIC is affected by NTP's time adjustment (time slewing). It won't jump, however.

Comment: But on newer kernels there is CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, which really isn't affected by NTP.

Comment: "tick" -- any rough idea how big/long/CPU instructions is a tick on Linux/amd64?  Or where I can get docs on any of this?

Comment: @kevinarpe Not sure but I think a tick is defined as a fraction of time, not a number of CPU cycle, often it’s 1/100 second.

Comment: @Stéphane: I surely must be tighter than 10ms.  I think Java's `System.nanoTime()` uses `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` and can measure _durations_ of 1000ns or less.  Maybe you are thinking about system time, which is sometimes limited to milliseconds?

Comment: As stated by Joseph, the CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW isn't affected by NTP but it is affected by variations of the local crystal oscillator on the motherboard. The frequency of these local oscillator varies with the local temperature, jitter and aging of the crystal.

Answer (score 26):

**POSIX 7 quotes**

POSIX 7 specifies both at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_getres.html:

`CLOCK_REALTIME`:

> This clock represents the clock measuring real time for the system. For this clock, the values returned by clock_gettime() and specified by clock_settime() represent the amount of time (in seconds and nanoseconds) since the Epoch.

`CLOCK_MONOTONIC` (optional feature):

> For this clock, the value returned by clock_gettime() represents the amount of time (in seconds and nanoseconds) since an unspecified point in the past (for example, system start-up time, or the Epoch). This point does not change after system start-up time. The value of the CLOCK_MONOTONIC clock cannot be set via clock_settime().

`clock_settime()` gives an important hint: POSIX systems are able to arbitrarily change `CLOCK_REALITME` with it, so don't rely on it flowing neither continuously nor forward. NTP could be implemented using `clock_settime()`, and could only affect `CLOCK_REALTIME`.

The Linux kernel implementation seems to take boot time as the epoch for `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`: [Starting point for CLOCK_MONOTONIC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726401/starting-point-for-clock-monotonic)

Comment: That's what I really wanted to know! Thank you!

Answer (score 22):

In addition to [Ignacio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3523482), `CLOCK_REALTIME` can go up forward in leaps, and occasionally backwards. `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` does neither; it just keeps going forwards (although it probably resets at reboot).

A robust app needs to be able to tolerate `CLOCK_REALTIME` leaping forwards occasionally (and perhaps backwards very slightly very occasionally, although that is more of an edge-case).

Imagine what happens when you suspend your laptop - `CLOCK_REALTIME` jumps forwards following the resume, `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` does not. Try it on a VM.

Comment: CLOCK_MONOTONIC starts at 0 when the program starts; it is not for interprocess use.

Comment: @Benubird: It does not start at 0 when the program starts. That's `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID`. Quick test: `$ perl -w -MTime::HiRes=clock_gettime,CLOCK_MONOTONIC -E 'say clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC)'` --> 706724.117565279. That number matches system uptime on Linux, but the standard says its arbitrary.

Comment: As an aside, I do not believe that the Linux behaviour where `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` stops over a suspend/resume is POSIX-conforming.  It's supposed to be the time since a fixed point in the past, but stopping the clock over suspend/resume breaks that.

Answer (score 8):

Sorry, no reputation to add this as a comment.  So it goes as an complementary answer.

Depending on how often you will call `clock_gettime()`, you should keep in mind that only *some* of the "clocks" are provided by Linux in the VDSO (i.e. do not require a syscall with all the overhead of one -- which only got worse when Linux added the defenses to protect against Spectre-like attacks).

While `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,...)`, `clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,...)`, and `gettimeofday()` are always going to be extremely fast (accelerated by the VDSO), this is *not* true for, e.g. CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW or any of the other POSIX clocks.

This can change with kernel version, and architecture.

Although most programs don't need to pay attention to this, there can be latency spikes in clocks accelerated by the VDSO: if you hit them right when the kernel is updating the shared memory area with the clock counters, it has to wait for the kernel to finish.

Here's the "proof" (GitHub, to keep bots away from kernel.org):
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/2aae950b21e4bc789d1fc6668faf67e8748300b7

Answer (score 1):

There's one big difference between CLOCK_REALTIME and MONOTONIC. CLOCK_REALTIME can jump forward or backward according to NTP.
By default, NTP allows the clock rate to be speeded up or slowed down by up to 0.05%, but NTP cannot cause the monotonic clock to jump forward or backward.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to clarify what "the system is suspended" means under this context.

I am reading `timefd_create` and from the manpage,
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html

> ```
>    CLOCK_BOOTTIME (Since Linux 3.15)
>           Like CLOCK_MONOTONIC, this is a monotonically increasing
>           clock.  However, whereas the CLOCK_MONOTONIC clock does
>           not measure the time while a system is suspended, the
>           CLOCK_BOOTTIME clock does include the time during which
>           the system is suspended.  This is useful for applications
>           that need to be suspend-aware.  CLOCK_REALTIME is not
>           suitable for such applications, since that clock is
>           affected by discontinuous changes to the system clock.
> ```

Based on the above description, we can indicate that `CLOCK_REALTIME` and `CLOCK_BOOTTIME` still count time when the system is suspended, while `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` doesn't.

I was confused about what "the system is suspended" mean exactly. At first I was thinking it means when we send `Ctrl + Z` from the terminal, making the process suspended. But it's not.

@MarkR's answer inspired me:

> Imagine what happens when you **suspend your laptop** - .... **Try it
> on a VM**.

So literally "the system is suspended" means you put your computer into sleep mode.

[image]

That said, `CLOCK_REALTIME` counts the time when the computer is asleep.

---

Compare the output of these 2 pieces of code

##### timefd_create_realtime_clock.c

copy from `man timefd_create`

```c
#include <sys/timerfd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <inttypes.h>      /* Definition of PRIu64 */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>        /* Definition of uint64_t */

#define handle_error(msg) \
        do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)

static void
print_elapsed_time(void)
{
    static struct timespec start;
    struct timespec curr;
    static int first_call = 1;
    int secs, nsecs;

    if (first_call) {
        first_call = 0;
        if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start) == -1)
            handle_error("clock_gettime");
    }

    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &curr) == -1)
        handle_error("clock_gettime");

    secs = curr.tv_sec - start.tv_sec;
    nsecs = curr.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec;
    if (nsecs < 0) {
        secs--;
        nsecs += 1000000000;
    }
    printf("%d.%03d: ", secs, (nsecs + 500000) / 1000000);
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct itimerspec new_value;
    int max_exp, fd;
    struct timespec now;
    uint64_t exp, tot_exp;
    ssize_t s;

    if ((argc != 2) && (argc != 4)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s init-secs [interval-secs max-exp]\n",
                argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &now) == -1)
        handle_error("clock_gettime");

    /* Create a CLOCK_REALTIME absolute timer with initial
        expiration and interval as specified in command line. */

    new_value.it_value.tv_sec = now.tv_sec + atoi(argv[1]);
    new_value.it_value.tv_nsec = now.tv_nsec;

    if (argc == 2) {
        new_value.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
        max_exp = 1;
    } else {
        new_value.it_interval.tv_sec = atoi(argv[2]);
        max_exp = atoi(argv[3]);
    }
    new_value.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;

    fd = timerfd_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, 0);
    if (fd == -1)
        handle_error("timerfd_create");

    if (timerfd_settime(fd, TFD_TIMER_ABSTIME, &new_value, NULL) == -1)
        handle_error("timerfd_settime");

    print_elapsed_time();
    printf("timer started\n");

    for (tot_exp = 0; tot_exp < max_exp;) {
        s = read(fd, &exp, sizeof(uint64_t));
        if (s != sizeof(uint64_t))
            handle_error("read");

        tot_exp += exp;
        print_elapsed_time();
        printf("read: %" PRIu64 "; total=%" PRIu64 "\n", exp, tot_exp);
    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

##### timefd_create_monotonic_clock.c

modify a bit, change `CLOCK_REALTIME` to `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`

```c
#include <sys/timerfd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <inttypes.h>      /* Definition of PRIu64 */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>        /* Definition of uint64_t */

#define handle_error(msg) \
        do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)

static void
print_elapsed_time(void)
{
    static struct timespec start;
    struct timespec curr;
    static int first_call = 1;
    int secs, nsecs;

    if (first_call) {
        first_call = 0;
        if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start) == -1)
            handle_error("clock_gettime");
    }

    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &curr) == -1)
        handle_error("clock_gettime");

    secs = curr.tv_sec - start.tv_sec;
    nsecs = curr.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec;
    if (nsecs < 0) {
        secs--;
        nsecs += 1000000000;
    }
    printf("%d.%03d: ", secs, (nsecs + 500000) / 1000000);
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct itimerspec new_value;
    int max_exp, fd;
    struct timespec now;
    uint64_t exp, tot_exp;
    ssize_t s;

    if ((argc != 2) && (argc != 4)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s init-secs [interval-secs max-exp]\n",
                argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // T_NOTE: comment 
    // if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &now) == -1)
        // handle_error("clock_gettime");

    /* Create a CLOCK_REALTIME absolute timer with initial
        expiration and interval as specified in command line. */

    // new_value.it_value.tv_sec = now.tv_sec + atoi(argv[1]);
    // new_value.it_value.tv_nsec = now.tv_nsec;

    new_value.it_value.tv_sec = atoi(argv[1]);
    new_value.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
    if (argc == 2) {
        new_value.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
        max_exp = 1;
    } else {
        new_value.it_interval.tv_sec = atoi(argv[2]);
        max_exp = atoi(argv[3]);
    }
    new_value.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;

    // fd = timerfd_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, 0);
    fd = timerfd_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, 0);
    if (fd == -1)
        handle_error("timerfd_create");

    // if (timerfd_settime(fd, TFD_TIMER_ABSTIME, &new_value, NULL) == -1)
    if (timerfd_settime(fd, 0, &new_value, NULL) == -1)
        handle_error("timerfd_settime");

    print_elapsed_time();
    printf("timer started\n");

    for (tot_exp = 0; tot_exp < max_exp;) {
        s = read(fd, &exp, sizeof(uint64_t));
        if (s != sizeof(uint64_t))
            handle_error("read");

        tot_exp += exp;
        print_elapsed_time();
        printf("read: %" PRIu64 "; total=%" PRIu64 "\n", exp, tot_exp);
    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

1. compile both and run in 2 tabs in same terminal
   `./timefd_create_monotonic_clock 3 1 100`
   `./timefd_create_realtime_clock 3 1 100`
2. **put my Ubuntu Desktop into sleep**
3. Wait a few miniutes
4. Wake up my Ubuntu by pressing power button once
5. Check the terminal output

Output:

The realtime clock stopped immedicately. Because it've counted the time elapsed when the computer is suspended/asleep.

```
tian@tian-B250M-Wind:~/playground/libuv-vs-libevent$ ./timefd_create_realtime_clock 3 1 100
0.000: timer started
3.000: read: 1; total=1
4.000: read: 1; total=2
5.000: read: 1; total=3
6.000: read: 1; total=4
7.000: read: 1; total=5
8.000: read: 1; total=6
9.000: read: 1; total=7
10.000: read: 1; total=8
11.000: read: 1; total=9
12.000: read: 1; total=10
13.000: read: 1; total=11
14.000: read: 1; total=12
15.000: read: 1; total=13
16.000: read: 1; total=14
17.000: read: 1; total=15
18.000: read: 1; total=16
19.000: read: 1; total=17
20.000: read: 1; total=18
21.000: read: 1; total=19
22.000: read: 1; total=20
23.000: read: 1; total=21
24.000: read: 1; total=22
25.000: read: 1; total=23
26.000: read: 1; total=24
27.000: read: 1; total=25
28.000: read: 1; total=26
29.000: read: 1; total=27
30.000: read: 1; total=28
31.000: read: 1; total=29
33.330: read: 489; total=518 # wake up here
tian@tian-B250M-Wind:~/playground/libuv-vs-libevent$
```

```
tian@tian-B250M-Wind:~/Desktop/playground/libuv-vs-libevent$ ./timefd_create_monotonic_clock 3 1 100
0.000: timer started
3.000: read: 1; total=1
3.1000: read: 1; total=2
4.1000: read: 1; total=3
6.000: read: 1; total=4
7.000: read: 1; total=5
7.1000: read: 1; total=6
9.000: read: 1; total=7
10.000: read: 1; total=8
11.000: read: 1; total=9
12.000: read: 1; total=10
13.000: read: 1; total=11
14.000: read: 1; total=12
15.000: read: 1; total=13
16.000: read: 1; total=14
16.1000: read: 1; total=15
18.000: read: 1; total=16
19.000: read: 1; total=17
19.1000: read: 1; total=18
21.000: read: 1; total=19
22.001: read: 1; total=20
23.000: read: 1; total=21
25.482: read: 2; total=23
26.000: read: 1; total=24
26.1000: read: 1; total=25
28.000: read: 1; total=26
28.1000: read: 1; total=27
29.1000: read: 1; total=28
30.1000: read: 1; total=29
31.1000: read: 1; total=30
32.1000: read: 1; total=31
33.1000: read: 1; total=32
35.000: read: 1; total=33
36.000: read: 1; total=34
36.1000: read: 1; total=35
38.000: read: 1; total=36
39.000: read: 1; total=37
40.000: read: 1; total=38
40.1000: read: 1; total=39
42.000: read: 1; total=40
43.001: read: 1; total=41
43.1000: read: 1; total=42
45.000: read: 1; total=43
46.000: read: 1; total=44
47.000: read: 1; total=45
47.1000: read: 1; total=46
48.1000: read: 1; total=47
50.001: read: 1; total=48
^C
tian@tian-B250M-Wind:~/Desktop/playground/libuv-vs-libevent$
```