# Starting point for CLOCK_MONOTONIC

Tags: linux, real-time

As I understand on Linux starting point for `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` is boot time. In my current work I prefer to use monotonic clock instead of `CLOCK_REALTIME` (for calculation) but in same time I need to provide human friendly timestamps (with year/month/day) in reporting. They can be not very precise so I was thinking to join monotonic counter with boot time.

From where I can get this time on linux system using api calls?

Answer (score 17):

Assuming the Linux kernel starts the *uptime* counter at the same time as it starts keeping track of the monotonic clock, you can derive the boot time (relative to the Epoch) by subtracting **uptime** from the **current time**.

Linux offers the system *uptime* in seconds via the [`sysinfo`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sysinfo) structure; the *current time* in seconds since the Epoch can be acquired on POSIX compliant libraries via the [`time`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/time.html) function.

```c
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>

int main(void) {
    /* get uptime in seconds */
    struct sysinfo info;
    sysinfo(&info);

    /* calculate boot time in seconds since the Epoch */
    const time_t boottime = time(NULL) - info.uptime;

    /* get monotonic clock time */
    struct timespec monotime;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &monotime);

    /* calculate current time in seconds since the Epoch */
    time_t curtime = boottime + monotime.tv_sec;

    /* get realtime clock time for comparison */
    struct timespec realtime;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &realtime);

    printf("Boot time = %s", ctime(&boottime));
    printf("Current time = %s", ctime(&curtime));
    printf("Real Time = %s", ctime(&realtime.tv_sec));

    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, the monotonic clock may not match up relative to boot time exactly. When I tested out the above code on my machine, the monotonic clock was a second off from the system uptime. However, you can still use the monotonic clock as long as you take the respective offset into account.

***Portability note***: although Linux may return current monotonic time relative to boot time, POSIX machines in general are permitted to return current monotonic time from any arbitrary -- yet consistent -- point in time (often the Epoch).

---

As a side note, you may not need to derive boot time as I did. I suspect there is a way to get the boot time via the Linux API, as there are many Linux utilities which display the boot time in a human-readable format. For example:

```
$ who -b
         system boot  2013-06-21 12:56
```

I wasn't able to find such a call, but inspection of the source code for some of these common utilities may reveal how they determine the human-readable boot time.

In the case of the `who` utility, I suspect it utilizes the [`utmp`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/utmp.5.html) file to acquire the system boot time.

Comment: Actually there is no syscall for that; the system boot time is recorded in utmp (/var/run/utmp) since at least the days of UNIX v6 :)

Answer (score 4):

http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/clock_getres.2.html:

> ```
>   CLOCK_MONOTONIC
>           Clock that cannot be set and represents monotonic time since some
>           unspecified starting point.
> ```

Means that you can use `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` for interval calculations and other things but you can't really convert it to a human readable representation.

Moreover, you prabably want `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` instead of `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`:

> ```
>   CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW (since Linux 2.6.28; Linux-specific)
>           Similar  to  CLOCK_MONOTONIC, but provides access to a raw hard‐
>           ware-based time that is not subject to NTP adjustments.
> ```

Keep using `CLOCK_REALTIME` for human-readable times.

Comment: Yes, I know difference between monotonic and realtime clock. I was trying to combine both approaches because dont want to store 2 timestamps in object - monotonic and realtime. I want use monotonic for work and somehow get information about starting point to later, on client side just add monotonic part to it.

Comment: I tried that once (on Windows, which has awful timing support).  The answer is: don't go there.  If you must, you can try to estimate the current monotonic-to-realtime offset by reading both clocks, but that offset can change without warning.

Comment: Link now reads "On Linux, that point corresponds to the number of seconds that the system has been running since it was booted."

Answer (score 0):

`CLOCK_MONOTONIC` is generally not affected by any adjustments to system time. For example, if the system clock is adjusted via NTP, `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` has no way of knowing (nor does it need to).

For this reason, don't use `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` if you need human-readable timestamps.

See [Difference between CLOCK_REALTIME and CLOCK_MONOTONIC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523442/difference-between-clock-realtime-and-clock-monotonic) for a discussion.

Comment: Linux did not get right `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`. To fix they added  `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW`.

Comment: CLOCK_MONOTONIC is monotonic but it can be adjusted. This is done by skewing the counter. Some ticks will take slightly more/less time than others in order to maintain time.