# Reliably find offset between two clocks on the same machine

Tags: linux, time, posix, real-time

The Linux man page for `clock_gettime(2)` does a good job of explaining the difference in meaning between `CLOCK_REALTIME` and `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`.   At any given time these two clocks will be offset by some varying offset.  I want to keep track of this offset.  A simple approximation would be

```
struct timespec rtime, mtime;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &rtime);   
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &mtime);
// subtract the timespecs here.
```

But there is an unpredictable delay between the two calls.  Can the kernel give me a reliable estimate of the offset in a single "atomic" operation?

BTW: I think the OP in [Starting point for CLOCK_MONOTONIC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726401/starting-point-for-clock-monotonic) wanted the same information.  But the responders there seemed to be answering a different question, so I thought I would ask it in my own words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[adjtimex](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/adjtimex.2.html) will return information regarding the state of how the system clock varies with respect to prior *adjtime* calls. This might not be exactly what you asked for but it might give you enough or equivalent information for whatever your needs are.

Comment: I think you are right in the sense that the answer `adjtimex` or nothing.  I suspect the answer probably really is nothing.

Comment: Well, Linux is all open-source code. So in theory one could create a kernel module or modify the kernel to get whatever information you are looking for.  But I doubt this is the way you or most people want to go in, and I'm not sure it would be worth the effort over adjtimex.

Comment: I was thinking about that.  It might not even be a kernel module proper, just a change to the vdso(http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html).  That would by way over the top for my needs, but perhaps a fun geek project.