# Incorrect time from clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts) API on armv7 architecture

Tags: embedded-linux

I am seeing incorrect time from clock_gettime which is part of librt library.

This is mostly seen when multiple processes are invoking the API frequently(say multiple times within a second).

Comment: Have you tried turning the computer off and on again?

Comment: Are you saying time of the "clock_gettime" API is not matching with your date command? Refer this ex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726401/starting-point-for-clock-monotonic