# can't align perf timestamp with system epoch time

Tags: linux, performance, perf

I'm using perf to do some optimization work. By using `perf script` to show my perf records and get results like this:

```
   MyServer 13631 [015] 2611179.755027: probe_app:stat_timer: (52bbe0)
   ......
```

I write a script to analysis the results and need to change timestamp to epoch timestamp (at least accurate in second).

To to this, I first get the host start up epoch timestamp

```
    $ date -d "`uptime -s`" +%s
    1562557105
```

And verified by adding the uptime

```
    $ cat /proc/uptime
    2612552.50 36615651.34
```

The the start epoch timestamp is correct.

But I found the perf timestamp 211179.755027 is not the elapsed seconds since system startup as document said, there are some error about 100s+. How to get accurate timestamp while exec "perf record"? I tried "-T" but it seems not work.

Comment: Please include the `perf` / `kernel` version in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The default clock used by `perf` (or the underlying `perf_event_open`) is not actually documented - so I would not necessarily rely on it to be any specific clock. Fortunately, `perf` allows you to chose a specific clock with the `-k` option. In general `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` and `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` are supported. Other clocks may be available depending on the events and version.

If you choose a specific clock, you can then use [`clock_gettime`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/clock_gettime) to get matching timestamps. I'm not aware of a simple way to do this [from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18490494/how-do-you-get-clock-gettime2-clock-in-shell), but a C program will do.

Comment: thanks @Zulan for your information. I have tried CLOCK_MONOTONIC, and write a simple test code to check it: "clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts); printf("sec=%d nsec=%d\n", ts.tv_sec, ts.tv_nsec);", the CLOCK_MONOTONIC time has the  same value as /proc/uptime, the perf timestamp still has an error about 100s+ than clock_gettime result. looks like the "-k  CLOCK_MONOTONIC" not work for my case.

Comment: Curious... On my system (Linux/perf 5.2.5 from Arch), there is a large difference (tens of seconds) between `/proc/uptime` and `CLOCK_MONOTONIC*`.  And a small difference between the two `CLOCK_MONOTONIC*` (hundreds of milliseconds). And the perf clocks match perfectly.

Comment: what I did is: run "sudo perf record sleep 1; ./test", ./test is my test app to get CLOCK_MONOTONIC, after that, run "sudo pref script" to check perf timestamp, I got "sec=2626411 nsec=206691096" from ./test and 2626311.114567 from perf script. My system (Linux version 3.10.0-514.26.1.el7.x86_64, CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810, perf 3.10.0)

Comment: I'm afraid the 6 year old Linux version doesn't support `perf` clock ids. That was introduced with Linux 4.1 (2015). I can't comment on what is backported in these  custom ancient Linux kernels