# vala: is this the correct way to get the current time in milliseconds ?

Tags: vala

Using this library with Vala :

http://valadoc.org/#!api=glib-2.0/GLib.DateTime

```
    GLib.DateTime now = new GLib.DateTime.now_local();

    var sec = now.to_unix()
    var msec = (sec * 1000) + now.get_microsecond();
```

is this the correct way to get the current time in millisecond ?

is there a better way ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

GLib.DateTime is a valid way of doing this, and it's a bit weird that you're requesting a local time then converting it to unix time (which implicitly converts to UTC).  The real problem, though, is that you're conflating milliseconds (1/1000th of a second) and microseconds (1/1000000th of a second).  So change the last line to

```
var msec = (sec * 1000) + (now.get_microsecond () / 1000);
```

Alternatively, an *easier* way would be to use [GLib.get_real_time](http://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/GLib.get_real_time.html):

```
int64 msec = GLib.get_real_time () / 1000;
```

Depending on your use case you might want to consider using monotonic time instead of real time (see [GLib.get_monotonic_time](http://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/GLib.get_monotonic_time.html)

Comment: Thanks!  I noticed that get_monotonic_time doesn't return the number of microseconds since January 1, 1970 UTC.
 get_real_time returns something else, (monotinic_time returned  587731122, while real_time returned 1382202816518 when they were both run within 5 minutes) How would I get a monotonic real_time (number of microseconds since January 1, 1970 UTC) ?

Comment: "monotonic real_time" is nonsensical.  If you need real time use get_real_time.  I only mentioned monotonic time because a lot of people who think they need real time would be better off using monotonic time (e.g., for measuring time between events).

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523442/difference-between-clock-realtime-and-clock-monotonic