# FIO runtime different than gettimeofday()

Tags: c++, linux, performance, io, execution-time

I am trying to measure the execution time of FIO benchmark. I am, currently, doing so wrapping the FIO call between gettimeofday():

```
gettimeofday(&startFioFix, NULL);
FILE* process = popen("fio --name=randwrite --ioengine=posixaio rw=randwrite --size=100M --direct=1 --thread=1 --bs=4K", "r");
gettimeofday(&doneFioFix, NULL);
```

and calculate the elapsed time as:

```
double tstart = startFioFix.tv_sec + startFioFix.tv_usec / 1000000.;
double tend = doneFioFix.tv_sec + doneFioFix.tv_usec / 1000000.;
double telapsed = (tend - tstart);
```

Now, the question(s) is

1. telapsed time is different (*larger*) than the *runt* by FIO output. Can you please help me in understanding Why? as the fact can be seen in FIO output:

   ```
   randwrite: (g=0): rw=randwrite, bs=4K-4K/4K-4K/4K-4K, ioengine=posixaio, iodepth=1
   fio-2.2.8
   Starting 1 thread

   randwrite: (groupid=0, jobs=1): err= 0: pid=3862: Tue Nov  1 18:07:50 2016
   write: io=102400KB, bw=91674KB/s, iops=22918, runt=  1117msec
   ...
   ```

   and the telapsed is:

   ```
   telapsed: 1.76088 seconds
   ```
2. what is the actual time taken by FIO execution:
   a) *runt* given by FIO, or
   b) *the elapsed time by getttimeofday()*
3. How does FIO measure its *runt*? (probably, this question linked to 1.)

PS: I have tried to replace the gettimeofday(with std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()), but it also behaves the same (by same, I mean it also gives larger elapsed time than *runt*)

Thank you in advance, for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick point:`gettimeofday()` on Linux uses a clock that doesn't necessarily tick at a constant interval and can even move backwards (see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html and https://stackoverflow.com/a/3527632/4513656 ) - this may make `telapsed` unreliable (or even negative).

1. Your gettimeofday/popen/gettimeofday measurement (`telapsed`) is going to be: the fio process start up (i.e. fork+exec on Linux) elapsed + fio initialisation (e.g. thread creation because I see `--thread`, ioengine initialisation) + fio job elapsed (`runt`) + fio stopping elapsed + process stop elapsed). You are comparing this to just `runt` which is a sub component of `telapsed`. It is unlikely all the non-`runt` components are going to happen instantly (i.e. take up 0 usecs) so the expectation is that `runt` will be smaller than `telapsed`. Try running fio with `--debug=all` just to see all the things it does in addition to actually submitting I/O for the job.
2. This is difficult to answer because it depends on what you want you mean when you say "fio execution" **and why** (i.e. the question is hard to interpret in an unambiguous way). Are you interested in how long fio actually spent trying to submit I/O for a given job (`runt`)? Are you interested in how long it takes your system to start/stop a new process that just so happens to try and submit I/O for a given period (`telapsed`)? Are you interested in how much CPU time was spent submitting I/O (none of the above)? So because I'm confused I'll ask you some questions instead: what are you going to use the result for and why?
3. Why not look at the source code? https://github.com/axboe/fio/blob/7a3b2fc3434985fa519db55e8f81734c24af274d/stat.c#L405 shows `runt` comes from `ts->runtime[ddir]`. You can see it is initialised by a call to `set_epoch_time()` (https://github.com/axboe/fio/blob/6be06c46544c19e513ff80e7b841b1de688ffc66/backend.c#L1664 ), is updated by `update_runtime()` (  https://github.com/axboe/fio/blob/6be06c46544c19e513ff80e7b841b1de688ffc66/backend.c#L371 ) which is called from `thread_main()`.