# What is "m=+" in GO time string?

Tags: go, time

I'm experimenting with Google OAuth2 and I encountered this in the expiry time of my refresh token. It comes from  `2018-10-15 15:42:37.5989253 +1100 AEDT m=+3610.688917401`

I know it's a time format but I couldn't find any information about `m=+` anywhere. Is it used internally by Google? I tried to parse it with `time.RFC3339` but as you can guess, it ignores the `m=+`. It says

> parsing time "2018-10-15 15:42:37.5989253 +1100 AEDT
>   m=+3610.688917401" as "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00": cannot parse "
>   15:42:37.5989253 +1100 AEDT m=+3610.688917401" as "T"

So what's this `m=+`  in the time string?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `m=±<value>` is [monotonic clock](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#hdr-Monotonic_Clocks) reading in second.

Explanation from [`time.Time.String` documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.String):

> If the time has a monotonic clock reading, the returned string includes a final field "m=±", where value is the monotonic clock reading formatted as a decimal number of seconds.

Afaik, golang doesn't provide layout for parsing monotonic clock, so *in my opinion* it's safe to remove it.

```
dateFormat := "2006-01-02 15:04:05.999999999 -0700 MST"
dateString := "2018-10-15 15:42:37.5989253 +1100 AEDT m=+3610.688917401"

t, err := time.Parse(dateFormat, strings.Split(dateString, " m=")[0])
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    os.Exit(0)
}

fmt.Println(t) // 2018-10-15 15:42:37.5989253 +1100 AEDT
```

Starting from [go 1.9](https://golang.org/doc/go1.9#monotonic-time), calling `.String()` will generate date string output with monotonic clock in it. So I suggest try to use `.Format()` for normal usage instead of `.String()`.

The monotonic clock info is only useful for debugging purposes.