# Get current time in microseconds

Tags: unix, time, ada

How can I get the current time in microseconds (formatted as integer64) in ada ?

I want to get the equivalent of C function clock_gettime (frome time.h).

Comment: "current time in microseconds (formatted as integer64)" is poorly defined. Typically what you want is a count of microseconds since some epoch, and "current time" usually means the epoch of the Common Calendar (0001-01-01 00:00:00 CE). Binding to a C function clock_gettime is well defined and probably what you want, but I'm unable to find any definition of time.h that includes it, so I can't help you further with that.

Comment: @JeffreyR.Carter i've try to import clock_gettime but i'm unable to find how to cast the parameters (parameters are `clockid_t` and `struct timespec`, see: https://users.pja.edu.pl/~jms/qnx/help/watcom/clibref/qnx/clock_gettime.html)

Comment: `clockid_t`  and `struct timespec` are platform dependent.

Comment: The description at users.pja.edu.pl does not provide enough information to bind to the function. However, it does say that it returns the elapsed time since the Unix epoch, so using Ada.Calendar and Ada.Calendar.Arithmetic.Difference as suggested by Wright and Holsti will give you what you want.

Comment: The description at users.pja.edu.pl says that `struct timespec` is "a structure containing at least the following members", so I think that to bind to `clock_gettime()` you’d have to create a C function to make the call and extract the values, then bind to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends when you want the count to start. If you want uptime, you’ll need to handle `clock_gettime()`. If you want time since the Unix epoch, this might help:

```ada
with Ada.Calendar;
with Ada.Text_IO;
procedure Get_Current_Time is

   type Integer_64 is range -2**63 .. 2**63 - 1;

   The_Unix_Epoch : constant Ada.Calendar.Time :=
     Ada.Calendar.Time_Of (Year  => 1970,
                           Month => 1,
                           Day   => 1);

   use type Ada.Calendar.Time;

   Time_Now : constant Ada.Calendar.Time := Ada.Calendar.Clock;

   Time_Since_Epoch : constant Duration := Time_Now - The_Unix_Epoch;

   In_Microseconds : constant Integer_64
     := Integer_64 (Time_Since_Epoch * 1.0e6);

begin

   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("result:" & In_Microseconds'Image);

end Get_Current_Time;
```

Or, instead of `The_Unix_Epoch`, you could store the current clock at the start of your program, if you just want elapsed time.

Comment: That solution would be nice, but it depends on the Duration type having a wider range than required by the Ada standard. By RM 9.6(27), Duration has to span at least one day (positive or negative), but does not have to span weeks, months, or years. The same calculation can be done in a standard way with Ada.Calendar.Arithmetic.Difference, which returns the difference between two dates as an integer day count and the fractional day in seconds as a Duration value. It also returns the number of leap seconds between the two dates.

Comment: @NiklasHolsti, yes, I’m being GNAT-centric

Answer (score 1):

You can use the QueryPerformanceCounter function of the Win32API to get the microsecond time. You can use the Ada.Win32.MicroTime package to encapsulate this function.
`with Ada.Win32.MicroTime;`

```
procedure Main is
   Time : Ada.Calendar.Time;
   MicroTime : Integer_64;
begin
   Time := Ada.Calendar.Clock;
   MicroTime := Ada.Win32.MicroTime.Get_Microseconds;
   -- Operating with MicroTime
  null;
end Main;`
```

Comment: I took a look at `Ada.Win32` but I'm working on Linux and this package is not provided

Comment: See also [_Difference between CLOCK_REALTIME and CLOCK_MONOTONIC?_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3523442/230513)

Answer (score 0):

On Linux (or other UNIX-like) systems, you can use the C library function clock_gettime to get microsecond time. You can call this function using the Ada.Clock_Time library.

```ada
with Ada.Real_Time;
with Ada.Clock_Time;

procedure Main is
   Time : Ada.Calendar.Time;
   MicroTime : Integer_64;
begin
   Time := Ada.Calendar.Clock;
   MicroTime := Ada.Real_Time.To_Integer_64(Ada.Clock_Time.Clock);
   -- Operating with MicroTime
   null;
end Main;
```

I hope this answer helps.

Comment: Where can we find `Ada.Clock_Time`?

Comment: In Ada programs, Ada.Clock_Time is a standard library package that can be found in the Ada standard library. You can introduce this package by using the with Ada.Clock_Time; statement. You need to make sure that your Ada compiler is properly installed and configured, and that it includes Ada's standard library.

Comment: Not in the ARM, not in the [GNAT RM](https://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/gnat_rm/html/gnat_rm/gnat_rm/standard_library_routines.html), not in FSF GNAT. What Ada compiler are you using?